# Cropping an image to a rectangle

Tags: android

I am trying to crop the image within the rectangle as image attachedI'm able to take and crop the picture. But the cropped image is not of same position. I don't want to use crop images library

[image: Camera View]

This is picture taken

[image: Captured Image]

This is cropped image, which i'm getting
[image]

This is my layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.example.android.camera2basic.AutoFitTextureView
    android:id="@+id/texture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rectangle"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"></RelativeLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/control"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="112dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/picture" />


</FrameLayout>
```

This is how i'm doing this

```
 Rect rectf = new Rect();

 //For coordinates location relative to the screen/display
 relativeLayout.getGlobalVisibleRect(rectf);

 Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(origBitmap, rectf.left, rectf.top, rectf.width(), rectf.height(), null, false);
```

Comment: Hi, did you found the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Bitmap's size is larger than the screen size, so you have to do some conversions. That is, compute the ratio (bitmap size/screen size), and then calculate the corresponding rect in pixels:

```
float ratio = bitmap size/screen size; // pseudo code
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(origBitmap, rectf.left * ratio,
        rectf.top * ratio, rectf.width() * ratio, rectf.height() * ratio, null, false);
```

Note: if the aspect ratio(width/height) of the bitmap is the same as the device, then the ratio is either `bitmapWidth/screenWidth` or `bitmapHeight/screenHeight`, if not, then you should consider about your way to display the bitmap(e.g. fill height or fill width?).

Comment: what's the result now? can you print the values, bitmap size, screen size, relative layout rect, etc. then you can analysis the process.

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq did you found the solution to your problem? I've the same issue and I'm interested by the solution if you got one, Thx

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
int x1 = Image.getWidth() * x_cordinateOfRextangle /  screenWidth;
int y1 = Image.getHeight() * y_cordinateOfRextangle / screenHeight;
int width1 = Image.getWidth() * widthOfRectangle / screenWidth;
int height1 = Image.getHeight() * heightOfRectangle / screenHeight;

Bitmap croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(Image, x1, y1, width1, height1);
```