# Crop a svg image and convert it to png

Tags: c#, svg, skiasharp

I have a big svg image.
I would like to crop it to a rectangle, using coordinates, and convert it to png image.

I have to say that I'm not used to drawing with c#.
Surface, Canvas and other notions are new to me.

I have figured out how to load the svg, using SkiaShark and SkiaShark.Svg:

```
var svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
svg.Load(tmpPath);
```

And found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/punker76/67bd048ff403c1c73737905183f819a9) that saves a png. But this is "Chinese" for me.

```
var imageInfo = new SKImageInfo(100, 100);
using (var surface = SKSurface.Create(imageInfo))
using (var canvas = surface.Canvas)
{
    // calculate the scaling need to fit to screen
    var scaleX = 100 / svg.Picture.CullRect.Width;
    var scaleY = 100 / svg.Picture.CullRect.Height;
    var matrix = SKMatrix.CreateScale((float)scaleX, (float)scaleY);

    // draw the svg
    canvas.Clear(SKColors.Transparent);
    canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture, ref matrix);
    canvas.Flush();

    using (var data = surface.Snapshot())
    using (var pngImage = data.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100))
    {
        tmpPath = Path.ChangeExtension(tmpPath, "PNG");
        using var imageStream = new FileStream(tmpPath, FileMode.Create);
        pngImage.SaveTo(imageStream);
    }
}
```

If someone could show me the directions, it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

---

I've come to this implentation myself, though it is not working...  The result bitmap is transparent and empty.

```
private string ConvertSVGToPNGRectangleWithSkiaSharpExtended(string path, double left, double top, double right, double bottom)
{
    var svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
    var picture = svg.Load(path);

    // Get the initial map size
    var source = new SKRect(picture.CullRect.Left, picture.CullRect.Top, picture.CullRect.Width, picture.CullRect.Height);

    // Cropping Rect
    var cropRect = new SKRect((int)left, (int)top, (int)right, (int)bottom);

    var croppedBitmap = new SKBitmap((int)cropRect.Width, (int)cropRect.Height);

    using var canvas = new SKCanvas(croppedBitmap);
    canvas.Clear(SKColors.Transparent);
    canvas.DrawBitmap(croppedBitmap, source, cropRect);

    var data = croppedBitmap.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);

    path = Path.ChangeExtension(path, "PNG");
    using var imageStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    data.SaveTo(imageStream);

    return path;
}
```

---

EDIT 2:
I'm sorry , if it is not clear. You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513854/cropping-an-image-to-a-rectangle) for doing so on Android.

Comment: The gist code works fine, what do you need to do exactly when you say "I would like to crop it to a rectangle, using coordinates"? can you post a source image and the expected result.

Comment: The gist is using desiredSizes values, which seems to implies to save the whole svg to a png. I'd like to save a part of the svg image, the famous rectangle in question.

Comment: What you want to do is unclear. Can you give what asked?

Comment: I've added a link to an equivalent question on Android

Comment: An SVG is a picture (not an image, they are not the same type of objects), it can't be cropped, so you must convert it to an image first and draw a portion of that image (DrawImage can do that while DrawPicture cannot) to another one. Check this code, it should do what you want: https://pastebin.com/raw/2rFFWN64

Comment: I have set up a private github repo whith a source SVG and the PNG outputed by your code, to play with if you want.  you can ask at omatrot_arobase_free.fr for me to invite you if you please.

Comment: Not sure I want to do that. My provided code just crops an SVG image and saves it as a PNG image, as requested in the question.

Comment: I tested your code against my svg file. It produces a transparent (or blank) png. My github repo contains the SVG for you to test the code you provided.

Comment: You should provide everything related to the question (code, svg, files, etc.) publicly here when possible (should be in this case) or under a public repo https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Unfortunately It is not the case. The SVG is 3532KB in size. Hence the github repo.

Comment: If my code works on a normal svg and doesn't work for a special particular one, this is a pure SKIA problem that you should report to google.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert with SkiaSharp, but I do know about drawing and canvases and I looked up the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skcanvas.drawpicture

I think the problem is this line:

`canvas.DrawBitmap(croppedBitmap, source, cropRect);`

I think you need:

```
canvas.DrawPicture(picture, -cropRect.Left, -cropRect.Top);
canvas.Flush();
```

I might have the coordinates wrong, but the problem behind your failure is that you are never drawing `picture` to the canvas.

To help with your confusion about what a canvas is: `SKCanvas(croppedBitmap)` is making it so that every time you draw to `canvas`, what you are actually drawing on is the bitmap. So in order to draw your picture onto the bitmap, you have to draw `picture` onto `canvas`. Using negative coordinates make it so the top and left of the svg picture are above and to the left of the top-left corner of the bitmap, which is the equivalent of having the bitmap start somewhere in the middle of the svg picture.

Hope this helps!